# Placing Several 3D Objects in Mathematica Together in the Same 3D Box

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, 3d

I have a 3D surface created by the ListPlot3D in mathematica. The surface itself is relatively planar and in the arbitrary plane xy. I would like to place this surface on top of a molecule either generated from the ChemicalData function or inputted from a .pdb or other molecule input. This molecule is also planar and placed again the in the xy plane. I would like these two 3D objects to be separated by some z distance.

The end hope is that I will have a potential energy surface placed above this planar molecule that will still be rotatable in 3D. I have been using the Show and Graphics 3D options to no success. The x,y points on the surface correspond to x,y points on the 3D molecule, however they can easily be scaled and shifted as needed. As an option of last resort I suppose I could input the x,y,z coordinates of the atoms and use the PointListPlot3D command with various options to mimic the look of the molecule but this seems to be much more complicated then it needs to be.

Another approach that could be possible is if both of the 3D objects are converted to 3D boxes and simply stacked on top of each other. However I have not found this functionality as of yet in mathematica. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

```
PES = ListPlot3D[{{0., 0., -2.04900365`},..., {0., 0.3, -2.05743098`}}]
Show[Graphics3D[ChemicalData["Benzene","MoleculePlot"]],PES]
```

The issue was the scale of the molecule versus the scale of the energy surface.

The units, as best I can tell, are in picometers. However their atomic distance seem to be off by 3%.

As an update to this it became much simpler to take the xyz coordinate of the molecule and hand generate the objects. It has been some time but I believe if you only state:

```
ChemicalData["Benzene","MoleculePlot"]
```

Mathematica will show you the format. If you do many of these a fairly simple python script can be made.

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `Graphics3D` and `Show`?  Please include the relevant information first, and provide examples if possible. (I.e. "this is my code, this what I got, and this is how the result is different from what I want")

Comment: PES = ListPlot3D[{{0.`, 0.`, -2.04900365`},..., {0.`, 0.3`, -2.05743098`}}]     Show[Graphics3D[ChemicalData["Benzene","MoleculePlot"]],PES]'

Comment: Thanks for the sample.  It's preferable to keep questions organized, so people who find them perhaps months or years later can still learn from them.  Could you edit your question and include this code, in context?  Use the `edit` link in it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips I will keep it in mind for the future. Now to figure out the scale that mathematica uses for the dimensions.

Comment: @Ophion, the coordinate units of `"MoleculePlot"` are picometres.  These are also available from `ChemicalData[...,"AtomPositions"]`.

Comment: Ah their data is somewhat skewed which is fine, but the molecule does does not have reasonable principle coordinates. Any idea on how to either align the molecule to a principle axis of orientation or convert a .mol (.pdb, etc) to a Graphics3D?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What Szabolcs said and I also did not get from your question why wouldn't something like this work?

```
    Show[Graphics3D[
  Rotate[ChemicalData["Caffeine", "MoleculePlot"][[1]], 
   45 Degree, {1, .5, 0}]], 
 Plot3D[-200 + 50 Sin[x*y/10000], {x, -100 Sqrt[3*Pi], 
   100 Sqrt[3*Pi]}, {y, -100 Sqrt[3*Pi], 100 Sqrt[3*Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing, I had no axes and did not notice the scale of the molecules. I am currently attempting to scale the molecule down to the correct size... the energy surface could not be displaying due to the radically different sizes involved.

Answer (score 5):

`ListPlot3D` returns a `Graphics3D` object, so you should be able to combine it with other `Graphics3D` objects...

```
lp = ListPlot3D[  RandomReal[{}, {50, 3}], Mesh -> None];
sp = Graphics3D[Sphere[]];
Show[sp, lp, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: a new gravatar]

although getting everything the same size will be the challenge...

Comment: @posterity I wrote this comment before the OP updated the question to show the code that they'd been using. It looks a bit of a silly answer now, I suppose... :}